# Is there a way to auto update constraints when UIView size changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

A view has 2 subviews stacked vertically. Each of these 2 views has a dynamic height: one of them loads an image from web, for which the height is not determined; the other is a web view which loads some html, and gets its height calculated after loading is done.

I want something similar to HTML's document flow to layout the 2 subviews, so I use iOS auto layout. But there are inconveniences:

1. I have to set a fixed height constraint for both views in Interface builder, and this constraint can not be deleted in IB.
2. When the height of the subviews are available (for the webview, using sizeToFit), I have to remove the fixed height constraint defined in IB, and add another height constraint with real height (view.frame.size.height).

This is very awkward. Is there a way to automatically re-layout views when their size changes?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a base concept of how auto layout works.  If you have two views that are edge-to-edge vertically then you shouldn't set a height constraint at all, instead set a constraint for the distance between the two views (if they are edge-to-edge then that can be zero) then when you resize the dynamic view the other view will resize appropriately as well based on its constraints.

The thing to remember here is that auto-layout can do all the heavy lifting but it won't take over if you set fixed height constraints and vary the vertical sizes so instead set constraints on the vertical distance between the two views and you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: I did set the distance between the subviews. The thing is, autolayout arranges the views based on constraints only, and ignores the actual size. In my case, I called sizeToFit which update the height of a view, but that doesn't change the layout, I have to manually update the height constraint with the new height to make it work. Correct me if I am wrong. And, if using interface builder, there is no way to NOT set a fixed height constraint, or is there?

Comment: Autolayout absolutely does not ignore size as it allows you to set fixed height, width or both.  However in the case of two views which stretch to the edge horizontally but don't have a fixed vertical size you want a constraint with relation to EACH OTHER, not one with fixed height.  And yes, you absolutely do not need to set a fixed height constant, just set the distance you want between the views horizontally and the size will stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have to remove the constraint that was defined in IB.
Just check the Placeholder Checkbox.

[image]